# Linear Layout, 2 items, align 2nd item to the right. Limit its interaction box to its size - how to add dynamic blank space

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a TextView and a Switch in a Linear Layout.

The way I can lay these two out is shown in the pictures below:

[image]

[image]

But what I actually want, is that the switch is on the right side (as in the 2nd picture) but the size box related to the switch is only as big as it needs to be (as seen in the 1st picture).

This is important for my OnClickListeners.
So I guess I am looking for a way to add a TextView (or whatever else, just a "div" like behaviour)  in between, which takes exactly the space available between the two, so that area becomes unclickable. But that area is dynamic, varying on different screen sizes.

Relevant Code:

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/terms_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                    android:text="@string/profile_permissions_user_data_accept_terms" />


                <Switch
                    android:id="@+id/permissions_accept_terms"
                    style="@style/Body"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                    android:gravity="end"/>


            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why not just use a `RelativeLayout` or `ConstraintsLayout`

Comment: I was just wondering what is possible within Android and how far one can manipulate layouts. I've taken the Relative Layout Approach.

Comment: Since you want to set a  view relative to other view then you have to use a layout which supports this.  Those are above two . Linear and frame layout does not support that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `RelativeLayout` or `ConstraintsLayout`. Because with these you can align one view to another view thats not possible with `LinearLayout`.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/terms_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/permissions_accept_terms"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:text="profile_permissions_user_data_accept_terms" />


    <Switch
            android:id="@+id/permissions_accept_terms"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Or

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/terms_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/permissions_accept_terms"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:text="profile_permissions_user_data_accept_terms" />


    <Switch
            android:id="@+id/permissions_accept_terms"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

To keep it within the LinearLayout you can assign it like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="end"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/terms_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:text="something" />


    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/permissions_accept_terms"
        style="@style/Body"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:gravity="end"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

By assiging a weight to the textfield you allow it to scale but equally, constrain the switch to always be the same side.
Textview changes:

```
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_weight="0.8"
```

Switch Changes:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

Linear Layout changes:

```
 android:gravity="end"
```

Gravity consistantly links to to the end of the layout.

Answer (score 1):

As you want to use `LinearLayout`, you cannot leave any empty space in the layout.

What you can do is to expand the `TextView` to match all the space left by the `Switch`, by using `layout_weight` attribute:

```
   <LinearLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal">

     <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="1"/>

     <Switch
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="0"/>

   </LinearLayout>
```